# Prevent direct access using the define and defined function in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the define function and the defined function in order to avoid hotlinking / direct accessing a PHP script but for some reason it will not work.

The issue I'm having is that it simply will not work and i recieve the "Hotlinking is not allowed" message even if i visit index.php first and follow the link and / or the post form.

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

**index.php**

```
<?php
define("ACCEPT",TRUE);
?>
<html>
...
```

**core.php**

```
<?php
if (defined('ACCEPT'))
{
// ACCEPT is defined which means the user came here via index.php
}
else
{
// The user is most likely direct accessing core.php, abort.
echo "Hotlinking is not allowed";
exit;
}
```

Please note that the post "Preventing Direct Access, is it possible to spoof a php define?" does not answer my question nor does the post "define and defined for disallow direct access".

Comment: If you have something that you don't want accessed directly, don't put it in the docroot.  Keep it outside.  You can still include it in other scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately my host does not allow me to access anything but the public_html root =/

Comment: You should get a new host!  Even my $3/mo. shared hosting allows me to get to that.  For $5/mo., you can get a solid VPS.

Comment: @Brad yeah i've been thinking about it for a while. It is, after all, very cheap nowadays.

Comment: Are you in some way including the core.php in index.php file?

Answer (score 2):

This is what a fair amount of programs do.  Just create a header that checks for the definition and redirect/exit if it isn't defined.  There is nothing wrong with doing it this way, but it just adds to the amount of lines/code each page will need.  This can be confusing because the DEFINE needs to be in one place, then the page requested has to either be included, or needs to include the page that has the define.  It is all about structure.

Here is something you can do:

.htaccess - redirects every request to index.php

index.php - Defines a variable, acts as a router that fetches/includes the page to be shown based on request data.

childpage.php - checks if variable exists (meaning it was included) and then does whatever needs to be done.

The other option is to place the sensitive code in am htaccess protected directory.

You can use a framework as well that does a lot of this.

Or, if your host allows you to edit your vhost config, which they probably won't if you only have access to a public directory, you can change the document root to a higher directory.

Comment: Could you please explain abit more what you mean by checking the headers? I mean, how do you check the headers and use define / defined

Comment: Ignore my first comment, I understand what you're trying to say.
Is there any other way to use the define function? It would be stupid in my case to use include to make an connection between index.php or core.php.